# Angular 4 app-selector does not initialize component life-cycle hooks

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I am using App-header selector in my app component when user login then i redirect him to home page where app header shows but constructor and other lifecycle hooks are not running but when i refresh then app-header component life-cycle hooks work.
any one know how to resolve what is causing this issue.My code is

```
<div id="tg-wrapper" class="tg-wrapper tg-haslayout">
    <app-header></app-header>
    <main id="tg-main" class="tg-main tg-paddingzero tg-haslayout">
            <div class="tg-main-section tg-haslayout">
                    <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">
                                    <div id="tg-content" class="tg-content">
                                            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
    </main>
    <app-footer></app-footer>
```

Comment: if i understand well, the home will be displayed after the <router-outlet> so there is no need for angular to "reload" the app-header. You should use your loginService ( or whatever ) to tells the app-header to load new infos after login. Maibe a Subject "isLogged$" who  will emit true after successfull login. Then subscribe to this Subject in your app-header component

Comment: Yes i got it Thank you bro.